# Como deixo minha DropDownListFor igual o Select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, html-helpers

Como faço pra deixa minha DropDownListFor, igual esse select onde o primeiro campo não pode ser selecionado.

```
<select>
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecionar</option>
  <option value="1">SEMANAL</option>
  <option value="2">MENSAL</option>
  <option value="3">ANUAL</option>
</select>
```

...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.MeetingFrequency, new SelectList(new List<Object> {
  new { value = "0", text ="Selecionar"},
  new { value = "SEMANAL", text = "Semanal" },
  new { value = "MENSAL", text = "Mensal" },
  new { value = "ANUAL", text = "Anual" }
}, "value", "text"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir o valor da propriedade `Disabled` de `SelectListItem` como `true`.

Pra isso funcionar, você vai precisar mudar um pouco a criação do drop down list. Ao invés de usar um objeto do tipo `SelectList`, use uma lista de `SelectListItem`.

Exemplo:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.MeetingFrequency, new List<SelectListItem> 
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Selecionar", Disabled = true},
    new SelectListItem { Value = "SEMANAL", Text = "Semanal" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "MENSAL", Text = "Mensal" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "ANUAL", Text = "Anual" }
}, "value", "text"))
```

Comment: Tentei deu esse erro: "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' não contém uma definição para 'Disabled"

Comment: Você está mesmo usando ASP.NET MVC **5**?

Comment: Bom não sei direito ele tem a propriedade Selected, Value, Text, mas agora mudei e esta dando certo estou fazendo no HTML mesmo

Comment: Se você não sabe não deveria ter usado a tag mvc 5. Vou ver como fazer em versões anteriores.

Comment: Não precisa ta ok, acho que selecionei a tag sem presta atenção

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.MeetingFrequency, new SelectList(new List<Object> {
  new { value = "0", text ="Selecionar",disabled = "disabled"},
  new { value = "SEMANAL", text = "Semanal" },
  new { value = "MENSAL", text = "Mensal" },
  new { value = "ANUAL", text = "Anual" }
}, "value", "text"))
```

Comment: Quase certeza que Isso não funciona com `SelectList`

Comment: É não funcionou

Comment: Desculpe, não prestei atenção. Não funciona com selectList. Altera para SelectListItem como o LINQ, respondeu. Que da certo.